# How can i change the bootstrap switch to mobile from 767 to 768?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My question sounds very easy but i doesn't found a solution by myself yet.

All i want is that the change to the mobile site (switching the navbar to a dropdown menu) happens when i have a `width: 768px` and not `width: 767px`. Reason for this is a iPad 2 with a width of 768px. For this type of devices i want to have the mobile site.

What i've already tried was to change the bootstrap css-file (all 768px values to 769px and all 767px values to 768px) but nothing happend.

Does anyone have an idea?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is your site calling bootstrap.css or bootstrap.min.css? You could be changing the stylesheet that isn't being called.

Comment: check all `@media ...` commands at .css

Comment: My site calling `bootstrap.min.css` but when i change it nothing happens.

Comment: Could you send us the link?

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A2RTA/) with the css where i changed all media-entries (768 to 769, 767 to 768).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change this quite easily if you compile bootstrap yourself. This isn't as difficult as it sounds, simply go here: [bootstrap download link](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download) and click the link that says "Download source" Inside of the folder called "less" will be some files with a .less extension. Using a less compiler ([here is a good free one](http://winless.org/)) you can then compile the bootstrap.less file into bootstrap.css. Now you can open up the file called variables.less and find the instance of 768 and change it to 767 and recompile bootstrap.less and your new bootstrap.css file that is created should work the way you want.

In the same way you can change any of bootstraps default behaviours (colour, width, height etc)

Answer (score 1):

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ allows you to set the @grid-float-breakpoint and download the custom files